# Moving code with struct usage from C to C++

Tags: c++, struct

I have problems moving code that uses struct data from C to a C++ class.
This struct `thread` is declared and an array of 3 elements is initialized.

```
static struct thread {
    const char *const filename;
    size_t buf_size;

    ssize_t (*in)(struct thread *, void *, size_t);
    const char *const in_name;

    ssize_t (*out)(struct thread *, const void *, size_t);
    const char *const out_name;

    int fd;
    pthread_t id;
    void *buf;
    ssize_t status;
} threads[] = {
    {
        "ep0", 4 * sizeof(struct usb_functionfs_event),
            read_wrap, NULL,
            ep0_consume, "<consume>",
            0, 0, NULL, 0
    },
    {
        "ep1", 8 * 1024,
            fill_in_buf, "<in>",
            write_wrap, NULL,
            0, 0, NULL, 0
        },
        {
         "ep2", 8 * 1024,
            read_wrap, NULL,
            empty_out_buf, "<out>",
            0, 0, NULL, 0
        },
};
```

Now I am declaring the struct in the header file outside my class like this:

```
struct stThread{
    const char *const filename;
    size_t buf_size;
    size_t (*in)(struct stThread *, void *, size_t);
    const char *const in_name;
    size_t (*out)(struct stThread *, const void *, size_t);
    const char *const out_name;
    int fd;
    pthread_t id;
    void *buf;
    size_t  status;
};
```

and as a private member of my class I create an array of 3 elements of this `struct`:

```
struct stThread threads[3];
```

When I compile I get these errors:

```
 In constructor "MyClass::MyClass(MyClass::UsbDescription*, void*)":
/MyClass.cpp:76:65: error: uninitialized const member in "struct stThread"
In file included from RDEmbeddedTools/FunctionFS.cpp:2:0:
MyClass.hpp:78:20: note: "stThread::filename" should be initialized
MyClass.cpp:76:65: error: uninitialized const member in "struct stThread"
```

What's wrong with my code here?
Also, how can I assign values to the 3 elements of the array `threads` in the constructor?
Is there a more comfortable way than this:

```
threads[0].filename = "foo";
threads[0].buf_size = 1024;
...
```

Comment: I think the error message is clear: error: **uninitialized const member** in "struct stThread"

Comment: Thank you, I was completely overlooking the const.